# Fubini's Theorem Holds After Changing a Condition in the Hypothesis

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Prove that the conclusion of Fubini's theorem remain in force if we replace the condition that $f$ is integrable by $\int\left(\int\left|f_x(y)\right| d \mu_2(y)\right) d \mu_1(y)<\infty$.

My solution: Simply by Tonelli's theorem, we get $\int |f| d\mu=\int\left(\int\left|f_x(y)\right| d \mu_2(y)\right) d \mu_1(y)<\infty$. Now we have the usual hypothesis for Fubini's theorem.

I doubt the solution is correct since the qustion is worth more marks in the exam.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is 100% correct.

Comment: $f$ should be measurable. Also you should integrate with respect to x and y, not twice with respect to y.